# Outlook opens the task in a modal window after I opened this task in a modal window from the application

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I open the task from my application using `Display(true)` method (modal window). After closing the task, an Outlook starts to open this task in a modal window. But when I close my application, an Outlook starts to open this task in a normal state window. Why is this happening? How to dispose of this problem?

Comment: You have to dispose the outlook interop object completely before exiting your application.

Comment: @RohitPrakash I need to open an Outlook task in a normal window, while my application is running. I tried to use `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject`, but it did not help.

Comment: It looks like you didn't release all underlying COM objects properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing and Wait for let it be clear in finally statement.

```
email.Close();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

Answer (score 0):

All Outlook add-ins should systematically release their references to Outlook objects when they are no longer needed. Failing to systematically release reference to Outlook objects can prevent Microsoft Office Outlook from shutting down properly.

I'd suggest using the ReleaseComObject method of the Marshal class instead. Calling the GC methods twice will hit the performance of .Net applications and take some time to finish. So, use *System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject* to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object.

You can read more about this in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) article in MSDN.